# Problems while installing XML::Parser-2.34

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

I was trying to install the XML::parser-2.34 for intltools on my Ubuntu 12.04, but encountered some error messages while testing it. I am not sure if those failed tests are vital or insignificant.

I checked the README file but did not find any help. If anyone can look up to the error message and tell me what does it mean and does it affect the installation process?

Here are the three failed tests:

```
t/encoding.t ...... Failed 1/6 subtests
t/external_ent.t .. Couldn't load LWP based external entity handler
Switching to file-based external entity handler
t/parament.t ...... Couldn't load LWP based external entity handler Switching to file-based external entity handler
```

Also I am not sure if `Expat` is needed for `XML::Parser` still because it is not mentioned as a necessary dependency from the [installation guide page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/general/perl-modules.html#perl-xml-parser) so if anyone knows whether that is a necessary thing before I install `XML::Parser` it would be great also.

Comment: Re "Also I am not sure if Expat is needed", From the distro's `README`: This is a Perl extension interface to James Clark's XML parser, expat.
It requires at least version 5.004 of perl and **it requires that you have
release 1.95.0 or greater of expat installed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages

```
Couldn't load LWP based external entity handler
```

aren't errors - they're just informational messages saying that the test has had to use a different technique because of the software that's available on your system

You have just one real error

```
t/encoding.t ...... Failed 1/6 subtests
```

and personally I'd let that go, as it is often the test that is wrong if it is a minority error. But if you're doing anything fancy with encoding you may want to check what that test was and see if you're ready to accept diminished functionality in that area

The 
[`XML::Parser`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser) module depends on the lower-level
[`XML::Parser::Expat`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser::Expat) module, but it is part of the same distribution, so there is no need to install it separately

Comment: Nice tips! Yeah I went ahead to install anyway and it seemed fine.